# jQuery - Como filtrar um arquivo JSON de um link externo?

Tags: jquery, json, url, filter

Tou com uma dor de cabeça que é o seguinte:
Preciso fazer um filtro por nomes do seguinte JSON (resumido)...

```js
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Peck Murphy",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "MEDICROIX",
    "email": "peckmurphy@medicroix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (992) 428-2202",
    "address": "219 McDonald Avenue, Tioga, Utah, 6059"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Rosalyn Mckay",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "COREPAN",
    "email": "rosalynmckay@corepan.com",
    "phone": "+1 (927) 507-3490",
    "address": "537 Rost Place, Thynedale, Wyoming, 5160"
  }
]
```

O ideal seria fazer o filtro dele pelo nome. Parece simples, mas a minha tarefa é fazer esse filtro do mesmo JSON, só que de um link externo, que é [esse aqui](https://quarkbackend.com/getfile/gcpolidoro/data-json) e, logo após, colocar as linhas que passaram pelo filtro numa tabela.

A minha dúvida é como faço pra filtrar esse JSON que está online por um valor inserido numa caixa de texto e mostre todos os dados da linha que passou pelo filtro? Já virei o manual do jQuery inteiro e nada que me salve. Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, serei muito grato.

O mais recente script em jQuery que fiz:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { // Filtro único para nome
  $('#Cons_Name').keyup( function () { // Cons_Name é a id de um input que o usuário insere o nome de alguém para filtro
    var json = $.getJSON('https://quarkbackend.com/getfile/gcpolidoro/data-json', function(data) {
      var arr = $("td").filter(function (ret, i) {
        return ret.name == $("#Cons_Name").val();
      })
      console.log(arr);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Nesta sua última tentativa, você recebeu alguma mensagem de erro? Qual foi a saída do comando console.log(arr) ? Note que você não está iterando sobre os valores do JSON e sim de uma tabela que está no seu HTML.

Comment: A saída foi "undefined". O que você quer dizer com "iterando" (desculpa, sou meio novato nessa área)

Comment: O seu loop com a função `filter()` está usando outras variáveis que não tem nenhuma relação com o JSON

Comment: Hm. talvez esteja errando nisso. Vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Fazendo a correção do filter de "td" para json (a variavel), apareceu isso aqui no console: `[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: undefined]`. Acho que tou no caminho certo né?

Comment: Modifique a sua pergunta para refletir o código que está tentando.

Comment: Qual filtro você que aplicar na saída JSON? Quais os atributos deseja exibir?

Comment: Dei uma atualizada na descrição da pergunta...

Comment: Consegui fazer o filtro. Vou deixar o JS aqui como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () { // Filtro único para nome
   $('#Cons_Name').keyup( function () { // Cons_Name é a id de um input que o usuário insere o nome de alguém para filtro 
     var dadoFiltro = $(this).val(),
         json = $.getJSON('https://quarkbackend.com/getfile/gcpolidoro/data-json', function(data) { 
             var arr = $(data).filter(function (ret, i) { 
                return ret.name == dadoFiltro;
             }); 
             console.log(arr); 
         }); 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Mas você consegue melhorar a performance desse código. Guarde primeiramente o resultado do json em uma variável na inicialização do documento é no keyup do seu input você só faz a filtragem em cima desse json guardado.

Comment: Nossa, o código ficou bem melhor. Valeu pela ajuda, Rafael. :)

Answer (score 2):

Amigo,

Acho que você não precisa buscar o JSON toda vez no evento keyup, exceto que você necessite passar o texto como parâmetro (que não está evidente no seu exemplo).

Segue exemplo funcional com os dados que você passou, fazendo append em uma tabela :

```html
<html>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="Cons_Name" />

    <table id="tabela">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>nome</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var dataJson = null;

        var renderData = function (data)
        {
            $("#tabela tbody").empty();
            $(data).each(function (i, item) {
                $("#tabela tbody").append("<tr><td>"+item.index+"</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>");
            });

        };

        $.getJSON('https://quarkbackend.com/getfile/gcpolidoro/data-json', function (data) {
            dataJson = data;
            renderData(data);
        });


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Cons_Name').keyup(function () {
                var nome = $('#Cons_Name').val();

                if (nome == void (0) || nome.length == 0) {
                    renderData(dataJson);
                } else {
                    //Parcial:
                    var arr = $(dataJson).filter(function (a, b) {
                        return b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(nome.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                    });
                    renderData(arr);


                    //Full
                    var arr2 = $(dataJson).filter(function (a, b) {
                        return b.name.toLowerCase() == nome.toLowerCase();
                    });

                    console.log(arr);
                    console.log(arr2);
                }


            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa colocação, Ericson. Mudei a função de OnKeyUp para OnChange. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda do jlHertel, consegui fazer um JavaScript que funciona o filtro pelo nome, apenas. Aqui está ele (ficou meio grande, mas está comentado e é bem compreensível):

```js
$(document).ready(function () { // Filtro único para nome
  $('#Cons_Name').change( function () { // Cons_Name é a id de um input que o usuário insere o nome de alguém para filtro
    var json = $.getJSON('https://quarkbackend.com/getfile/gcpolidoro/data-json', function(data) {
      var arrMestre = []; // Um array que vai conter todos os cadastros (em arrays) (ver abaixo)
      var arrInfo = []; // Um array onde será guardado informações de um cadastro e limpo, depois, para a inserção do próximo cadastro
      var x = 0; // Auxilia na contagem da posição do arrMestre
      var y = 0;
      var posTabela = 1; // Aponta onte está o nome no arrInfo
      var resultNum = 0; // Conta o total de cadastros que passa pelo filtro
      $.each(data, function (i, arq) {
        arrInfo = []; // Limpeza para inserção do próximo cadastro
        arrInfo.push(arq.index);
        arrInfo.push(arq.name);
        arrInfo.push(arq.age);
        arrInfo.push(arq.gender[0]); // Detalhe interessante: o zero faz com que seja buscado apenas o primeiro dígito do sexo, fazendo com que ele seje M ou F. Economiza bastante tempo e espaço
        arrInfo.push(arq.company);
        arrInfo.push(arq.email);
        arrInfo.push(arq.phone);
        arrInfo.push(arq.address);
        arrMestre[x] = arrInfo; //O array com um cadastro é inserido no Mestre
        x++;
      });
      console.log(arrInfo);
      console.log(arrMestre); // Para ver se está tudo indo bem
      $("#tbResults tbody").empty(); // Limpa a tabela para inserir os dados
      for (var i = 0; i < arrMestre.length; i++) { // Passa por todos os cadastros do arrMestre
        var resultado = "<tr class='active'>"; // Variável que vai ser ".append()" na table que mostra o resultado. (Sim, em Bootstrap)
        if (arrMestre[i][posTabela].indexOf($("#Cons_Name").val()) >= 0) { // O coração do filtro: vê se o valor do text input (considerado como substring) está presente no nome. Se o resultado for -1, significa que não foi localizado o texto do usuário.
          resultado += "<td>" + (arrMestre[i][0] + 1 ) + "</td>"; // O "index" do meu código começava em zero, daí adiciona +1 no código
          for (var j = 1; j < arrMestre[i].length; j++) { // Todas as informações do cadas
            resultado += "<td>" + arrMestre[i][j] + "</td>"; // Vai inserindo os valores das células da table; Nome, idade, gênero...
          }
          resultado += "</tr>" // Fim da linha (literalmente)
          $("#tbResults tbody").append(resultado); // Insere a linha na tabela
          resultNum++; // Aumenta o número total de resultados em 1
        }
      }
      if (resultNum == 1) {
        var resultText = "Foi encontrado <b> um </b> resultado."
      } else {
        var resultText = "Foram encontrados <b>" + resultNum + "</b> resultados."
      }
      $(".panel-footer .resultNum").empty(); // Limpa o texto com o número de resultados anterior (detalhe pro panel-footer)
      $(".panel-footer .resultNum").append(resultText); // Insere o valor total de resultados
    });
  });
});
```